# Do I need to have company website to submit app to Appstore

Tags: ios

I notice apps t appstore have company website, a web site for the app, and support email.
do I need all of these, I don't reprsent a company. i'm developer only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need a company, you can be an independent developer, but you do need a website, a web page for the app and an email where people can send support requests. You can always use a free service like Google sites to host you pages initially.

Comment: I notice some app have support as a page in their website, for me, would email support will be enough?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you need both a support email address and a support URL. The support page does not have to be anything fancy. It can be as simple as directing users to the email address; though as you progress you will probably find it useful to put tips, FAQs or the like on it.